VS 2022 pair to mac "Could not install ios workload"
I am trying to pair to mac using windows VS 2022, and am receiving the following error:

Could not install workload 'ios'. Details: Unhandled exception:
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestCompositionException:
Could not find workload 'ios' extended by workload 'maui-ios' in
manifest 'microsoft.net.sdk.maui'
[/Users/MY/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/8.0.3/WorkloadManifest.json]

Both computers have VS 2022/VS for mac, mono installed, x-code installed.
What am I missing?
